# check data based on other data csv using pandas

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, csv

i have two data csv
The first :

```
word,centroid
she,1
great,0
good,3
mother,2
father,2
After,4
before,4
.....
```

The second:

```
sentences,label
good mother,1
great father,1
```

I want to check each sentence based on the cluster results
so if the sentences is `good mother` `good` on the `centroid` 3 then array will be [0,0,0,1,0] and word `mother` on the `centroid` 2 then array will be [0,0,1,1,0]...

I have complicated and wrong code ... can anyone help me

this is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
array=[]
data = pd.read_csv('data/data_komentar.csv',encoding = "ISO-8859-1") 
df = pd.read_csv('data/hasil_cluster.csv',encoding = "ISO-8859-1") 
for index,row in data.iterrows():
    kalimat=row[0]
    words=re.sub(r'([^\s\w]|_)', '', str(kalimat))
    words= re.sub(r'[0-9]+', '', words)
    for word in words.split():    
        kata=word.lower()
        df = df[df.eq(kata)]
        if df.empty:
            print("empty")
        else:
            print(kata)
            if df['centroid;'] is 0:
                array=array+[1,0,0,0,0]
            if df['centroid'] is 1:
                array=array+[0,1,0,0,0]
            if df['centroid'] is 2:
                array=array+[0,0,1,0,0]
            if df['centroid;'] is 3:
                array=array+[0,0,0,1,0]
            if df['centroid;'] is 4:
                array=array+[0,0,0,0,1]
            print(array)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply()` on the `sentences` column of the DataFrame:

```
import numpy as np

MAX_CENTROIDS = 5

def get_centroids(row):
    centroids = np.zeros(MAX_CENTROIDS, dtype=int)
    for word in row.split(' '):
        if word in df1['word'].values:
            centroids[df1[df1['word']==word]['centroid'].values]+=1
    return centroids

df2['centroid'] = df2['sentences'].apply(get_centroids)
```

Result `df2`:

[image]

`df1` is the DataFrame with your words and centroids, `df2` with the sententes. You have to specify the maximal number of centroids in `MAX_CENTROIDS` (=length of the centroid list).

**Edit**

To read the datasample you provided:

```
# Maybe remove encoding on your system
df1 = pd.read_csv('hasil_cluster.csv', sep=',', encoding='iso-8859-1')

# Drop Values without a centroid:
df1.dropna(inplace=True)

# Remove ; from every centroid value and convert the column to integers
df1['centroid'] = df1['centroid;'].apply(lambda x:str(x).replace(';', '')).astype(int)

# Remove unused colum
df1.drop('centroid;', inplace=True, axis=1)
```

Comment: i have an error on `centroids[df1[df1['word']==word]['centroid'].values]=1`    `IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type`

Comment: i have trouble because my centroid data is `she,1;
great,0;
good,3;
mother,2;` in python.... how to remove ; in my data...

Comment: @MuhammadRusli please provide a data-sample. But if it is a string, e.g. `data = 'she,1; great,0; good,3; mother,2;'`, you can use `df1 = pd.DataFrame([x.split(',') for x in data.replace(' ', '').split(';')[:-1]], columns=['word', 'centroid'])`

Comment: my sample data : `word centroid;`
`0                   dna        4;`
`1             structure        3;`
`2                   key        3;`
`3              labelled        3;`
`4                    pn        2;`

Comment: but in data csv nothing `;`

Comment: @MuhammadRusli, can you provide a data-sample of your csv data? Upload and post a link?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JMG_0iRPx6sGlKoiqVgu6TgRpgEDyLd9/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Yes, maybe excel doesn't show the `;`. I edited my answer to read and process the data. You could give it a try.

Comment: I have a sentence in Indonesian `Cara mengajarnya bagus dan mudah dipahami`  which should be the result `[4,0,0,0,2]` because `cara,4`
`mengajarnya,0`
`bagus,0`
`dan,0`
`mudah,4`
`dipahami,0`

Comment: in the part where I can sum the value of the array based on centroid?

Comment: Ah, ok you want to sum the values, small modification: add a `+` to the assign of the values: `centroids[df1[df1['word']==word]['centroid'].values]+=1`. And by the way: Cara (with a capital C) is 1, not 4 ;-)

Comment: Happy to help :-) You could [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), ff my solution helped you